# "PGError: no connection to the server" while trying to create or save

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Ruby 1.9.1 + ActiveRecord 2.3.5 + Postgres 8.3.7

Here is a rough sketch of my code. Ignore any obvious syntax details left out. The model below inherits from ActiveRecord::Base connected to a Postgres 8.3.7 database via ActiveRecord 2.3.5.

```
class TableA
   has_many :tableB
end

class TableB
   belongs_to :tableA
   has_many :tableC
end

class TableC
   belongs_to :tableB
   has_many :tableD
end

class TableD
   belongs_to :tableC
   has_many :tableE
end

class TableE
   belongs_to :tableD
end

# Note that tableA has fids that are referenced in tableE but is not part of this model
#
# Later in the script, in the same global scope, I want to add entries to these tables if
# I cannot find what I need. Bear in mind that this part betrays much Ruby noobiness.

toAdd.each do |widget|
   add_tableA = TableA.find_by_sql().first # assumes I will get one back based on earlier sanity checks

   add_tableB = TableB.find_by_sql().first
   if (add_tableB == nil)
       new_tableB = TableB.new( # value assignments )
       new_tableB.save
       add_tableB = TableB.find_by_sql().first
   end

   add_tableC = TableC.find_by_sql().first
   if (add_tableC == nil)
       new_tableC = TableC.new( # value assignments )
       new_tableC.save
       add_tableC = TableC.find_by_sql().first
   end

   add_tableD = TableD.find_by_sql().first
   if (add_tableD == nil)
       new_tableD = TableD.new( # value assignments )
       new_tableD.save
       add_tableD = TableD.find_by_sql().first
   end

   # I step into TableA again because items in TableE are linked to items in TableA, but they are
   # distinct from the "high level" item I grabbed from TableA earlier.

   add_tableA = TableA.find_by_sql().first
   if (add_tableA == nil)
       new_tableA = TableA.new( # value assignments )
       new_tableA.save
       add_tableA = TableA.find_by_sql().first
   end

   # Now that I have a TableA id to put into TableE, just create TableE row because I know this
   # does not exist yet.

   new_tableE = TableE.new( # value assignments ) # again, this is assumed to be new based on earlier checks
   new_tableE.save

end
```

What always happens is I get the following stack trace:

```
/...gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `rescue in log': PGError: no connection to the server (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
: ROLLBACK
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `log'
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:550:in `execute'
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:576:in `rollback_db_transaction'
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:143:in `rescue in transaction'
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:125:in `transaction'
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `block in save_with_transactions!'
    from .../gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from .../gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save_with_transactions!'
```

.... regardless if I'm calling save, save!, or doing a create instead of new and save.

strace reveals that I can only get one BEGIN..INSERT..COMMIT transaction to work for each run of this. Any subsequent attempts to INSERT within a transaction either in the same run of the loop or the next one ends with the connection being dropped before a COMMIT is sent. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong here with how I'm stepping into the ActiveRecord model.

I see the following strace only just before the first successful INSERT statement is set up. Is there something in ActiveRecord that allows me to preserve this as I step through tables, or am I simply Doing It Wrong?

```
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x1, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3876c0eb10}, {0x4b2ff0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3876c0eb10}, 8) = 0

sendto(3, "Q\0\0\2e          SELECT attr.attna"..., 614, 0, NULL, 0) = 614

rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x4b2ff0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3876c0eb10}, {0x1, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3876c0eb10}, 8) = 0

poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])

recvfrom(3, "T\0\0\0:\0\2attname\0\0\0\4\341\0\2\0\0\0\23\0@\377\377\377\377\0"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 541
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It cannot connect to the server, have you properly configured your database-server and is running in the right mode?

Comment: Thank you, but I discovered the problem not long after my last edit. This instance of postgres depends upon a second process to run to handle pushing trigger events out to other processes. That process was not running, so the database server booted after the first committed INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I apologize for taking anyone's time in trying to fix this. This instance of postgres depends upon a second process to run to handle pushing trigger events out to other processes. That process was not running, so the database server booted after the first committed INSERT. It's a custom in-house kind of thing.